Product add & remove is not working from sale admin in opencart
I am working in Opencart and face issue with product delete and add  within the order from order info page in sale admin side. I try with fresh install Opencart and facing same issue
Can anyone tell what exactly the issue is?
Not getting the solution yet

opencart version?

You cannot delete products from admin if this product added to some order. Bcz its make broken logic, if some customer buy product, and you want delete it. How customer can refund or do some with his order if product already deleted?
So if you want delete product, you must first way delete orders with that product included
